# Storing a block in a collection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

Is it possible to directly store a block in a collection such as NSArray?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, blocks are valid Objective-C objects, following all the conventions of NSObject. Just do the copy/autorelease dance:

```
[array addObject:[[block copy] autorelease]];
```

For ARC - omit the copy and autorelease calls:

```
[array addObject:block];
```

Comment: @Joseph Because the block exists on the stack, when the stack frame disappears after storing the block the reference in the array becomes invalid. As a good practice, after using the array, you should set it to nil

Comment: Surely the block on the stack gets a +1 ref (through ARC anyway) when it's added to the array though and so is still valid?

Comment: If ARC can determine the block is allocated on the stack it will automatically do the copy, but if it can't tell if the block is already on the heap it won't do the copy.  This can happen when a block is passed into a method.  The compiler can't tell if it is was allocated on the stack or heap.

Answer (score 1):

Can't figure out how to respond in the comment thread on Eimantas' answer, but -copy is necessary because the block may have been created on the stack. See 2) in [bbum's post on the topic](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/).

Comment: No, you can't reply directly to a comment. Just create a new comment below it :)